# Error while getting private key from .p12 file using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto

Tags: .net, cryptography, encryption

I am using the following code to get private key using "Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto" in .Net

```
        FileStream keyFileStream = File.OpenRead(FileName);
        char[] pwd = Password.ToCharArray();
        Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store store = new Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store(keyFileStream, pwd);

        System.Collections.IEnumerator h = store.Aliases.GetEnumerator();
        h.MoveNext();
        object o = h.Current;
        string alias = o.ToString();

        Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.AsymmetricKeyEntry privAsymKey = store.GetKey(alias);// as RsaKeyParameters;
        RsaKeyParameters privRSAKey = (RsaKeyParameters)privAsymKey.Key;
```

**But I get "privAsymKey" as null**

I tired manual method of [Getting private key using OpenSSl](http://sycure.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/tips-using-openssl-to-extract-private-key-pem-file-from-pfx-personal-information-exchange) and I could get the private key, which means that .p12 file is proper.

Can anyone help me to fix where exactly I am going wrong in getting the privatekey from .p12 file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After too much of googling, I found the following code which helps me to get the private key from .p12 file using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto

```
//This is the function call
 AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = TransformRSAPrivateKey(Certi.PrivateKey);
```

//This is the definition of the function which return Privatekey

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider prov = privateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
        RSAParameters parameters = prov.ExportParameters(true);

        return new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.Modulus),
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.Exponent),
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.D),
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.P),
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.Q),
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.DP),
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.DQ),
            new BigInteger(1, parameters.InverseQ));
```